# Linux/POSIX: Why doesn't fork() fork *all* threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, fork, posix

It is well-known that the default way to create a new process under POSIX is to use `fork()` (under Linux this internally maps to `clone(...)`)

What I want to know is the following: It is well-known that when one calls `fork()` "The child process is created with a single thread--the one that called `fork()`"
(cf. https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). This can of course cause problems if for example some other thread currently holds a lock. To me not also forking all the threads that exist in the process intuitively feels like a "leaky abstraction".

So I would like to know: What is the reason why only the thread calling `fork()` will exist in the child process instead of *all* threads of the process? Is there a good technical reason for this?

I know that on [Multithreaded fork](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6056903/497193) there is a related question, but the answers given there don't answer mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of these two possibilities:

- only the thread calling `fork()` continues running in the child process

  Downside: if another thread was holding on to an internal resource such as a lock, it will not be released.
- after `fork()`, all threads are duplicated into the child process

  Downside: threads that were interacting with external resources continue running in parallel. If a thread was appending data to a file: now it happens twice.

Both are bad, but the first one choice only deadlocks the new child process, while the second choice results in corruption outside of the process. This could be described as "bad".

POSIX did standardize `pthread_atfork` to try to allow automatic cleanup in the first case, but [it cannot possibly work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605487).

tl;dr Don't use both threads and forks. Use `posix_spawn` if you have to.