# Multi-threaded fork()

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, locking, fork

In a multi-threaded application, if a thread calls fork(), it will copy the state of only that thread. So the child process created would be a single-thread process. If some other thread were to hold a lock required by the thread which called the fork(), that lock would never be released in the child process. This is a problem.
To counter this, we can modify the fork() in two ways. Either we can copy all the threads instead of only that single one. Or we can make sure that any lock held by the (other) non-copied threads will be released. So what will be the modified fork() system call in both these cases. And which of these two would be better, or what would be the advantages and disadvantages of either option?

Comment: Don't.  The pthreads working group worked themselves into a corner, and dug an escape hatch whereby all of the inherent complexity of their bad design (*) was thrust on the user as a requirement.  Even innocuous calls like `system()` get caught in this web.  (*) design, because quite apart from standardization as an agreement upon common elements, the ieee-pthreads group set out to design something entirely new, and stamp standard upon it.  It only works if you don't press too hard on the seams; and yes I was part of the working group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a thorny question.

POSIX has [`pthread_atfork()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_atfork.3.html) to work through the mess of mixing forks and thread creation. The NOTES section of that man page discusses mutexes etc. However, it acknowledges that getting it right is hard.

The function isn't so much an alternative to `fork()` as it is a way to explain to the pthread library how your program needs to be prepared for the use of `fork()`.

In general not trying to launch a thread from the child of fork but either exiting that child or calling exec asap, will minimize problems.

This post has a [good discussion of `pthread_atfork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620313/how-to-use-pthread-atfork-and-pthread-once-to-reinitialize-mutexes-in-child).

Comment: Could you explain or point me towards pthread_atfork() code? How is its code different from fork() ? What extra things are added there? Thanks.

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer. Including a link to another post that includes some code.

Answer (score 0):

> ...Or we can make sure that any lock held by the (other) non-copied threads will be released.

That's going to be harder than you realize because a program can implement "locks" entirely in user-mode code, in which case, the OS would have no knowledge of them.

Even if you were careful only to use locks that were known to the OS you still have a more general problem: Creating a new process with just the one thread would *effectively* be no different from creating a new process with all of the threads and then immediately *killing* all but one of them.

Read about why we don't kill threads.  In a nutshell: Locks aren't the only state that needs to be cleaned up. Any of the threads that existed in the parent but not in the child could, at the moment of the fork call, been in the middle of making a mess that needs to be cleaned up.  If that thread doesn't exist in the child, then you've lost the knowledge of what needs to be cleaned up.

---

> we can copy all the threads instead of only that single one...

That also is a potential problem. The one thread that calls `fork()` would know when and why `fork()` was called, and it would be *prepared* for the fork call.  None of the other threads would have any warning.  And, if any of those threads is interacting with something *outside* of the process (e.g., talking to a remote service) then,where you previously had one client talking to the service, you suddenly have *two* clients, talking to the same service, and they both think that they are the only one.  That's not going to end well.

---

Don't call `fork()` from multi-threaded programs.

In one project I worked on: We had a big multi-threaded program that needed to spawn other processes.  How we did it is, we had it spawn a simple, single-threaded "helper" program before it created any new threads.  Then, whenever it needed to spawn another process, it sent a message to the helper, and the helper did it.